# Android-programmatically bypass remove default lock screen

Tags: android, launcher

I've defined a default application as a launcher with a HOME intent so it always runs when I boot the device.
But I still see the default lock screen(with clock) first when I power up.

Is there a way to remove the lock screen entirely when the device powers up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using following command you can disable the existing lockscreen of course if it doesn't contain any security(like patterns and pin code):

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

you need also to declare permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Than detect the user presence (clicking on Power Button):

```
<receiver android:name=".Receive">
    <intent-filter android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and start custom lockscreen Activity

Comment: actually I don't need the receiver and just put the lockscreen activity in my Main onCreate

Comment: Will this settings be restored when app gets closed?