# How to use smart lock API in my application to unlock pattern mode?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, google-smartlockpasswords

I am using Android 5.0. The version provides the SmartLock function which allows unlocking the password/pattern by connecting with a trusted device. I have a bluetooth low energy (BLE) device which registered as trusted device. I want to use the BLE to unlock (pattern mode) the phone. It will unlock the phone when the BLE and phone are connected and data is available by the event

```
if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) 
// Calling unlock by the SmartLock API
```

If anyone who worked with SmartLock, please give me some guidance to do it? I did not find any SmartLock API to do it. 
[image]

Comment: If BLE device added as trusted device in your smart lock settings then your device will automatically unlock when your phone is connected with that BLE device. What you are looking for is still unclear to me. Please elaborate on this and correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: You are right. But it has one more screen (swipe screen). It that time, we must scroll the screen to unlock. I want to ignore this. I think Smartlock has that option

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246425/turning-on-screen-from-receiver-service/30365638#30365638

Comment: Sorry. It is for swipe mode. I tried it but the code does not work in swipe of smartlock. I think swipe of smartlock has something different with normal swipe mode

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score 1):

There is no external API as such for SmartLock. You can check Google [Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/) for reference on it.

You can check [this](https://github.com/obaro/SmartLockSample) sample out on GitHub and [here](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-integrate-smart-lock-in-android-apps-702638/) you will find the tutorial on how to integrate smart lock API in your app.

Comment: If I trully understand, the smartlock which you give me is different with smartlock in my question. I ran the smartlock in the link before but it is only for email, not for pattern mode

Comment: @user8430 Well, yes. This tutorial is to give you a basic idea of the Smartlock. Like previous answers, you can use the `KeyguardManager` to unlock your device.

Comment: I think you did not try it before. Please have an experiment before answer

Comment: I think smartlock with email is different with smartlock in Android L, such I show in the image. It only has trusted device, trusted face, trusted location options. It has no option for email

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Answer (score -1):

It might be a little bit complicated, but Google already huge provided [Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/get-started) about this usage.

To request stored credentials, you must create an instance of `GoogleApiClient` configured to access the Credentials API.

```
mCredentialsApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .enableAutoManage(this, this)
    .addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API)
    .build();
```

A CredentialRequest object specifies the sign-in systems from which you want to request credentials. Build a `CredentialRequest` using the `setPasswordLoginSupported` method for password-based sign-in, and the `setAccountTypes()` method for federated sign-in services such as Google Sign-In.

```
mCredentialRequest = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
    .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
    .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE, IdentityProviders.TWITTER)
    .build();
```

After you have created `GoogleApiClient` and `CredentialRequest` objects, pass them to the `CredentialsApi.request()` method to request credentials stored for your app.

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsClient, mCredentialRequest).setResultCallback(
    new ResultCallback<CredentialRequestResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(CredentialRequestResult credentialRequestResult) {
            if (credentialRequestResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // See "Handle successful credential requests"
                onCredentialRetrieved(credentialRequestResult.getCredential());
            } else {
                // See "Handle unsuccessful and incomplete credential requests"
                resolveResult(credentialRequestResult.getStatus());
            }
        }
    });
```

On a successful credential request, use the resulting Credential object to complete the user's sign-in to your app. Use the `getAccountType()` method to determine the type of retrieved credentials, then complete the appropriate sign-in process.

```
private void onCredentialRetrieved(Credential credential) {
    String accountType = credential.getAccountType();
    if (accountType == null) {
        // Sign the user in with information from the Credential.
        signInWithPassword(credential.getId(), credential.getPassword());
    } else if (accountType.equals(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)) {
        // The user has previously signed in with Google Sign-In. Silently
        // sign in the user with the same ID.
        // See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/
        GoogleSignInOptions gso =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .setAccountName(credential.getId())
                .build();
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use the feature before? I am confusing your code API (with password) and smartlock which used trusted device

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync

Comment: @NirmalSinhRevar Spamming your question everywhere is not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a SmartLock API. Like Pravin said in the comments, smart lock will automatically disable the pattern when the device is connected.

I haven't tried this, but once the pattern is disabled you should be able to bypass the lock screen with the following (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20747940/4476553)):

```java
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

You will need to add a permission to your manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Comment: I tried it before but it can not unlock the swipe of smartlock

Comment: I am facing some issue in password sync. can you please have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830860/app-and-website-saved-password-is-not-sync